# How to fix up fonts displaying only in bold or italic after copying Windows/Fonts?

Tags: opensuse, kde, fonts

In order to fix up the broken display of some Word (Windows) files in LibreOffice, I copied over the entire `/windows/Fonts` path to `file://` (using dolphin via `kdesu`). The file displays better, but now many system fonts seem to display either in bold or italic, but rarely they the way they used to. What did I screw up and how can I revert this?

Comment: You copied them where? Sounds like you managed to overwrite some existing fonts.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx I'm afraid so :-/ Guess I have to reinstall them, any idea how to do that the least painfully?

Comment: Check which font packages you have installed, they usually contain ttf in their name. Also check what Opensuse has for ensuring system/package integrity — there's surely a tool to make sure the packages are still fully installed. Alternativelly you can just blankly reinstall all the packages on your system.

Comment: @lynxlynxlynx I reinstalled all installed font packages, to no avail. Either KDE decided to change my fonts settings on its own or reinstallation does not replace the files that shouldn't have been overwritten. In fact, I _did_ choose to not overwrite any files when I copied over the `windows/Fonts` directory, so this is really weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the font packages was futile. Instead, I had to change the KDE Font settings to use non-broken fonts - they were all set to "Sans Serif" which looks the same in bold as in normal. Changing that to a working one like "Free Serif" fixed this, though I would have preferred figuring out what actually went wrong...

---

**update** Installing the [webcore-fonts](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show?package=webcore-fonts&project=home%3Anferenc) package fixed the actual issue of broken Arial, Sans Serif etc.

Comment: note to self: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Font-HOWTO/fix.html